# would break up join into subsets of joins better than join all of them?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, time-complexity

my goal is to do a simple inner join between two tables:

```
select table1.*
from table1
join table2
using (col1, col2, col3)
```

when table1 is too big, this might leads to timeouts. both tables are being partitioned on `col1` and clustered on `col2, col3`

On the other hand, i might do

```
select t1.*
from (select * from table1 where col1 <= 1000) t1
join (select * from table2 where col1 <= 1000)
using (col1, col2, col3)
union all 
select t2.*
from (select * from table1 where col1 > 1000) t2
join (select * from table2 where col1 > 1000)
using (col1, col2, col3)
```

i wonder, what's the difference between those two queries performance wise? if helpful, i'm using Bigquery engine here. and of course, i can further breakup the conditions of `col1` to make even more no. of subqueries.

Comment: If the second version avoids the timeouts, then consider using it.  The second version is, overall, more work than the first version.

Comment: i'm not 100 sure if second version is avoiding timeouts, since the timeout is also very related to available slots in my org. so i was hoping some ppl with BQ insights can shed some light here. supposedly filter on partitioned fields will reduce the data amount, and two different subquery can benefit from reduced cross product. but that is my guess..

Comment: SQL is a declarative language - which basically means you write what you want to achieve rather than how to achieve it. The query optimizer then determines the best way of achieving the result. So most of the time, just write your SQL in the simplest way possible and let the query optimizer take care of things - you only need to start looking at different tuning approaches if you facing issues. If your 2 queries produce the same result, it is possible that the query optimizer actually runs the same execution plan for both

Comment: lol, turns out there is a blogpost about this particular issue https://medium.com/google-cloud/breaking-up-very-large-bigquery-jobs-ea1ccc720a7

Answer (score -1):

Based on the blogpost by google cloud https://medium.com/google-cloud/breaking-up-very-large-bigquery-jobs-ea1ccc720a7

Indeed, the second query is somewhat performant due to BQ's "smart" dynamically redistribute data implementation.